# Static Factory Method is creating a new object everytime its invoked

Tags: java, static, factory

In Effective Java its mentioned that "Unlike constructors static factory methods are not required to create a new object each time they're invoked".

```
class Car{
     String color;
     Boolean spoiler;

     public Car(String s){
        color=s;
        spoiler = false;
     }

     public static Car redCar(){
        return new Car("red");
    }
  }
```

In Main Class:

```
    Car c2 = Car.redCar();
    Car c3 = Car.redCar();
```

c2 and c3 are different objects. I did not get the context of "not required to create a new object each time invoked".

Comment: have a look at what is Singleton pattern

Comment: You forgot the important part of the passage: *This
allows immutable classes (Item 15) to use preconstructed instances, or to cache instances as they’re constructed, and dispense them repeatedly to avoid creating unnecessary duplicate objects*

Comment: You missed the **are not required** part. Your implementation clearly returns new instances every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because that's what you do:

```
public static Car redCar(){
    return new Car("red");
}
        //  ^ here
```

If you want to return the same value you can do something like:

```
private static final Car RED_CAR = new Car("red");

public static Car redCar(){
    return RED_CAR;
}
```

The point is that calling `new Car()` will *always* return a new instance. Calling `Car.newInstance()` means that the `Car` class can *decide* what to do.

For example:

```
private static final Map<String, Car> CARS = new HashMap<>();

public static Car newInstance(final String colour){
    return CARS.computeIfAbsent(colour, Car::new);
}
```

This uses the `Car` constructor as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to the new [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method, which calls it if a `Car` of that colour is not already present in the `Map`. This is a naive (not threadsafe) cache implementation.

So:

```
final Car one = Car.newInstance("red");
final Car two = Car.newInstance("red");
System.out.println(one == two) // true
```

Answer (score 4):

"Unlike constructors static factory methods are not **required** to create a new object each time they're invoked". This does not mean calling a static factory method will **necessarily** return the same object (as your example shows), only that it **may** (unlike a constructor).

You could, e.g., implement `redCar()` differently so it always returns the same object:

```
class Car{
     /* snipped */

     private static final RED = new Car("red");

     public static Car redCar(){
        return RED;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe cars are not the best example, but consider a requirement that says that your factory should produce only one car per color. You would implement it like this (omitting unnecessary attributes):

```
class Car {
    String color;

    public Car(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public static Car car(String color) {
        Car car = CARS.get(color);
        if (car != null) return car;
        car = new Car(color);
        CARS.put(color, car);
        return car;
    }

    private static final Map<String, Car> CARS = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Have a look at the [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class and its factory method [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). Additionally, such a factory method is useful for singletons (although they have their own caveats).

Comment: Or `cars.computeIfAbsent(color, Car::new)`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29797041/2071828). Further, please stick to Java naming conventions, compile time constants should be in `CAPITAL_UNDERSCORE_CASE`.

Answer (score 2):

As in everything, programs do exactly what you ask them to do. If your static method uses "new" each time when it is called; then you create new object each time.

What is meant by `unlike constructors static factory methods are not required to create a new object each time they're invoked"` is the fact that your code **can** decide to not call new; but for example return a "cached" object.

Meaning: when you use "new"; you call constructors; and the semantics of Java lead to the creation of a **new** object. There is no way preventing had, it is hardwired into the language.

But when you use static methods, **you** define the semantics of that method.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are creating new objects,

```
return new Car("red");
```

Static factory methods will be used to create object once for the first time and then return same instance next time when returned from static factory methods.

Answer (score 1):

Factory's job is to create an object. If you don't want to expose how the object is created, you hide the creation under factory.

Lately I have happened to work on a use case where the concept of singleton is defined based on some added restrictions. E.g., All File objects that capture file1.txt are singleton (or are same object). Similarly File objects that capture file2.text are singleton. However File objects that capture file1.text and file2.text are different.

For this to work, create a static global list that add your so called static objects (e.g., based on file name). If you don't want Singleton (again file based) objects to add to this list override equals.

Now if someone asks the factory to give you an object that matches what you specified in equals (what ever parameters make two objects equal), search the global list and if that object exists return it, else create a new object, add it to the list and then return the object.

The moral of the story is, yo don't have to return new objects from factory. You can bend Singleton to your need (if you don't need pure Singleton). And by using static factory method, one can call ClassName.factory without having to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea Bloch describes is that a static factory can use a **pool or cache** of instances that it passes when requested or decide on its inner logic to create a new instance (which may make into the cache too). This usually works only for **immutable objects** as otherwise you'd have some hard-to-track cross object effects.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation you have given is not a static factory. You have make the class as below:

```
class Car{
     String color;
     Boolean spoiler;
     public static final Car car = new Car("name");

     public Car getInstance(){
        return car;
     }
     private Car(String s){
        color=s;
        spoiler = false;
     }

     public static Car redCar(){
        return new Car("red");
    }
  }

and then in main you have to call

Car.getInstance();
```